# Brake fluid to be used on a 1960 Chevrolet Corvair

Tags: brakes

I have a 60  Corvair and have never changed the Brake Fluid.   I am planning to flush out the old fluid and replace it.   What brake fluid should I replace it with.   Dot 2,3,or 4

Answer (score 2):

Check the master cylinder cap, but you should use either DOT3 or DOT4 fluid without issues (Valvoline has fluid which is [DOT3 & 4](http://www.valvoline.com/products/brands/valvoline/dot-3-4-brake-fluid/28) ... this is to tell people you can use it for either application, though it will perform as DOT4). Stay away from DOT5 because it would no be compatible with your system (basically, anyway ... there are a plethora of reasons to stay away from it with an older car like yours). DOT2 will not provide the amount of brake fluid protection you'll need (I don't think you can even buy it anymore as brake fluid). It is actually castor oil based and will not give you the performance you'll need. Seeing as how the brake fluid has not been changed in forever, you'll want to do a thorough flushing of the system. Even when you think you have flushed it completely, flush it a little more. A power bleeder can be of great assistance here.